# Else statement not executing inside while loop of SQL database

Tags: java, sql

Else statement not working inside while loop

```
public void loginButton() throws ClassNotFoundException, SQLException{
        Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
        Connection con = (Connection) DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/finditdb","root","root");
        Statement stmt = con.createStatement();
        String usernameInput = usernameField.getText();
        String passwordInput = passwordField.getText();
        ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM finditdb.login WHERE username like '" + usernameInput +"' and password like '" + passwordInput +"'");
        while(rs.next()){
            String usernameDb = rs.getString("username");
            String passwordDb = rs.getString("password");
            if(usernameInput.equals(usernameDb) && passwordInput.equals(passwordDb)){
                System.out.println("Access Granted..");
            }
            else {
                System.out.println("Access denied..");
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Is `Access Granted` getting printed?

Comment: If your query fails to find data for some reason (data does not exist or incorrect `like `pattern), no rows will be returned and so `rs.next()` will return `false` and if I understand right, the control won't enter the `while` loop. That is the reason why your `else` condition will never really run if the `query` does not fetch anything. `rs.next` will return `true` and point to the next record if there is any or will return `false` if there is none.

Comment: yes Acces is printed if the input is true

Comment: but if the input is wrong, the access denied is not printed.

Comment: If the input is wrong, your query will return no result, right?

Comment: yes, how can i make it return to return the "Access Denied"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> You could try this and let me know if it works the way you want it to.

```
while(true){     
     if(rs.next()){
        String usernameDb = rs.getString("username");
        String passwordDb = rs.getString("password");
        if(usernameInput.equals(usernameDb) && passwordInput.equals(passwordDb)){
            System.out.println("Access Granted..");
            break;
          }

     }

     else{
            System.out.println("Access denied..");
            break;
     }
    }
```

We haven't mentioned any exit condition within the `while loop` parenthesis, so the loop keeps running till no more records are left to be fetched (else will print `Access denied` and break) or if access is granted (breaks again).

Comment: if the while loop has no condition inside, an error occur "error: illegal start of expression" appears.

Comment: Use `while(true)`. My bad. I missed that out. Sorry. I have edited the answer to correct it.

Comment: Great. Happy to help you :) Happy Learning